# DEBUG or RELEASE Mode ios when archieving

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am about to push my app to App Store and I am confused about debug or release flag.

My project setting look like this

[image]

I am just wondering that when I archive my code and sign it with the distribution profile, then will my application will be in **Debug** or **Release** mode.

Comment: For AppStore - Its in Release mode.

Comment: Please don't use iPhone tag if your question is not specifically about iPhone devices. See the tag wiki for iPhone for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be in release mode for it is the reason you are using a distribution profile.